# Silverlight 4:How to delay Mouseenter event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i have a situation where : User moves mouse over the image .

If user keeps mouse on that image for specific time ex. 2 seconds then only i have to proceed

further in  mouseenter event otherwise don't.

I have already refred to http://forums.silverlight.net/t/86671.aspx/1 but looks like mine is different case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a DispatchTimer to determine the length of the mouse over.

```
bool isMouseOverImage = false;
public void Image_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  this.isMouseOverImage = true;
  var timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
  timer.Tick += (object timerSender, EventArgs timerArgs) =>
  {
     if(this.isMouseOverImage)
     {
       // write your code 
     }

     // stop the timer
     timer.Stop();     
  };
  timer.Start();
}

public void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  this.isMouseOverImage = false;
}
```

If you have multiple images, you should create a re-usable [Behavior](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Behaviors-and-Triggers-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) and attach it to each image. I can define code for that if that would help.

Comment: Yes..it worked. I have also got other solutions like using backgroundworker or normal thread but safest way is DispatcherTimer as it runs under main UI thread